# Implementing a Custom Request

Tags: typescript, express, parameters, interface, request

I'm trying to implement a Custom Request object in express js with typescript. I want to simply modify the req.body object, or implement an interface for params too without touching other things.

```
import { Request, Response } from 'express';

interface CustomRequest<T> extends Request {
    body: T
}

interface ReqBodyInterface {
    username: string,
    email: string,
    password: string,
    password2: string
}

export function UserSignupPostHandler(
    req: CustomRequest<ReqBodyInterface>,
    res: Response
){
    // ...
}
```

And I was wondering the difference with this code,
with this one below('as' keyword):

```
const NewBody = res.body as PersoneModel;
```

And also with this code below. In this case, I'm scared about
making undefined/null the other fields like params, queries, etc. I don't know which one to use to be honest.

```
interface ReqBodyInterface {
    username: string,
    email: string,
    password: string,
    password2: string
}

export function UserSignupPostHandler(
    req: Request<{}, {}, ReqBodyInterface >,
    res: Response
){
    console.log(req.body.email);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the type aliases to type the request param as follows:

```
import { Request as ExpressRequest, Response } from 'express';
import * as core from 'express-serve-static-core';

interface ReqBodyInterface {
  username: string,
  email: string,
  password: string,
  password2: string
}

export type Request = ExpressRequest<core.ParamsDictionary, any, ReqBodyInterface>;
```